# How complete are the access logs for Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to process access logs for HTTP traffic to Google Cloud Storage buckets (in particular, I want to store the GET params into my database for analytics).

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-logs

> Caution: Timeliness and completeness of usage logs delivery is not guaranteed.

What does this mean exactly?

Am I going to be missing 0.0001% of logs, or more like 5%?

This is important as I want to use the logs to calculate usage based billing for my customers.

Comment: Use audit logs instead of usage logs. Except if you have a dedicated use case. in this case, let us know more

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I have never noticed missing data. However, access logging is a best-effort delivery. Google does not publish statistics that will answer your question.

I would not use access logs to generate billing statements. I would use separate buckets, export billing data to BigQuery, and query for cost data. That technique will ensure that you are not missing billing data and the data matches what Google bills your account.

Use the access logs as supplemental data for billing reports.

[Export Cloud Billing data to BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/export-data-bigquery)